# DBGo INSERT INTO via SQL.CommandText

Tags: delphi

I have taken the habit to use `SQL.TEXT` variable to initialize my queries in order to avoid two statements: `SQL.Clear; SQL.Add( );` using DBExpress.

Using dbGo for a new small project, this makes:

```
SQL.CommandText := 'INSERT INTO LeaveClass (id,name,color,status) VALUES (1,''Joe'',255,''Ok'')';
ExecSql;
```

This command breaks with a syntax error. But if we use:

```
SQL.Clear;
SQL.Add( 'INSERT INTO LeaveClass (id,name,color,status) VALUES (1,''Joe'',255,''Ok'')' );
ExecSql;
```

It works fine! Well I have wasted some time before catching up this problem and find its way around. What errors do I do? May be the `dbGo.ADOQUERY.Sql.Clear` makes a deep cleaning that the assignment via `dbGo.ADOQUERY.SQL.CommandText` doesn't. Weird. Any commands?

Comment: What is the type of dbGo.ADOQUERY.Sql?

Comment: Waht type of object are you using? ADOQuery? ADOCommand?

Comment: IMO, it should be `dbGo.ADOQUERY.SQL.Text := 'INSERT ...` or `dbGo.ADOQUERY.CommandText := 'INSERT ...`. Seems there's a mix up...

Comment: You talk about using SQL.Text, but then write something utterly different.

Comment: BTW, I hope you are using parameters in your real code...

Answer (score 4):

`CommandText` really only works for `SELECT` or other operations that return data (recordsets). It's not designed for `ExecSQL` or `INSERT`/`DELETE` type operations.

Simply use `ADOQuery.SQL.Text` instead:

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO LeaveClass (id,name,color,status) VALUES (1,''Joe'',255,''Ok'')';
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
ADOQuery1.Close;
```

Setting the `Text` property directly automatically replaces what was there before, removing the need for `Clear`.